# Magento 1.x vs Magento 2.x

Tags: magento, migration, magento-1.9, magento2

I'm working on Magento 1.9.3.7 and I want to understand if is a good idea to migrate to Magento 2 or not.

I summarized this differences :

- Magento 2.0 is faster then Magento 1.x
- Some significant changes in the structure of directory which reduces
  the complexity of structure
- New technologies and latest versions (example Php, Jquery etc)
- Allows developer to setup automated test easily
- Many features are now integrate to Magento 2
- Improvements to checkout and other stuff

My questions:

1. There is any index to look up to decide when is a good moment to migrate to Magento 2?
2. There are any hidden issue I have to know before?
3. Someone ever try this migration? If yes do you see this big improvement?
4. All my modules (third parts & hand-written) will be obsolete?
5. Why Magento 1.x is still releasing new security updates if there is Magento 2?

I hope to listen to different experencies or solution to understand if is the right way.

Please if I said something wrong tell me.

Docs on Internet (differences) : https://gauge.agency/articles/the-differences-between-magento-1-and-magento-2-and-which-is-better/

Comment: please consider to move your question to magento.stackexchange.com. It has less to do with general programming and is more magento related

Comment: I think you should read this article: [Magento 1 vs Magento 2](https://next-cart.com/magento-1-vs-magento-2-would-it-be-a-huge-step-forwards/). They also provide migration service from Magento 1 to 2.

Answer (score 3):

Having worked extensively with both platform, I have to say that Magento Inc's reasons for upgrading to m2 are just silly.

> Magento 2.0 is faster then Magento 1.x

This is not really true, right? Reasons why they say that M2 is faster is that it supports php 7.x and runs Varnish. To this, I say, so what? M1 does as well.

Community efforts like this one work like a charm: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7 (I'm in no way affiliated with Inchoo).

**Edit**: This is now even less true since M1 (as of 1.9.4) supports 7.2 without third party modules.

On the other side M2 has a semi working asset precompiling system, which keeps causing issues on every turn. Further more, it slows the development to such degree that M1 feels like a blazing fast solution.

(If you think that this should be an outrageous exaggeration, which it should probably be, but sadly isn't, check out some of the [GH issues](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7859#issuecomment-268214155).

> Some significant changes in the structure of directory which reduces the complexity of structure

This was a great idea, but the actual result is terrible. How the hell did M2 end up with more configuration and more XMLs? What's with the XML heavy UI components?

Is this the example of the simplified module structure – https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog?

Yeah sure, M1 is not great here, but M2 did not improve here at all, just check out the amount of the xmls in a single module – https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc

> New technologies and latest versions (example Php, jQuery etc)

Sure, and stuff like ZF1, KnockoutJS and [Fotorama](https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/532).

> Allows developer to setup automated test easily

I agree here. M2 has a proper support for automated testing, while M1 has almost none.

> Many features are now integrate to Magento 2

I'm not sure what exactly you wanted to say here, but the problem I had is that they simply migrated features from M1 to M2, didn't improve them at all, slapped new interface on top of it and call it new platform.

While there's no problem here, I feel like this was a huge opportunity to improve the system, but they dropped the ball.

> Improvements to checkout and other stuff

I disagree, checkout is now not as nearly flexible as it was. Working with KnockoutJs and UI Components is the last thing you want to do.

I'm fine with it being quirky and all, but the flexibility and possibility to improve checkout per particular shop is nowhere near M1.

> There is any index to look up to decide when is a good moment to migrate to Magento 2?

Most of the Magento agencies are using this to promote their services and offer migrations to M2 as a way to make extra profit. So you'll always see companies talking about performance and feature improvements which aren't there.

This is the only case where someone says something differently: https://amasty.com/blog/magento-1-vs-magento-2-performance-comparison-speed-test-results/ (I'm in no way affiliated with Amasty).

> There are any hidden issue I have to know before?

Platform is not stable enough, major bugs are still present. Just do a quick browse through issue reports on GH.

> Why Magento 1.x is still releasing new security updates if there is Magento 2?

There are lots of businesses that will never migrate to M2. They have no option here.

Lastly, I want to say that I'm sorry for all the hate in this answer, really wasn't my intention. :D

Comment: I agree with every single statement XD. But you have to admit, M2  has built-in redis based FPC

Comment: If I want to upgrade to M 2.2 I have to first migrate to 2.0 then install all upgrades or I can migrate directly to 2.2?

Comment: Not sure really. I try not to upgrade. ;)

Comment: Just to complement to @MladenIlić the support to Magento 1 will be only until 2019. That's a very good factor to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> There is any index to look up to decide when is a good moment to
>   migrate to Magento 2?

It depends on individual store environment (Big stores with own ESB may use M2 as storefront, small ones will have to wait until their ERP Provider releases a plugin or connector)

> There are any hidden issue I have to know before?

M2 code architecture is nothing like M1. MVC has been dropped in favour of MVVM

> Someone ever try this migration? If yes do you see this big
>   improvement?

yes. FPC has been improved alot and general ttfb response is a way better

> All my modules (third parts & hand-written) will be obsolete?

yes, due different design patterns.

> Why Magento 1.x is still releasing new security updates if there is
>   Magento 2?

Magento inc. has promised ongoing support for M1. There are too many enterprise customers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration a few times before. But for me, there is only one reason I can think that stands out, to do such a major overhaul on a website, and that is security,

You should not just upgrade to Magento 2, but specifically 2.3 as it has a lot more invested in security and less prone to malware attacks. It also has new features that did not exist in Magento 2.2.

If you are still on Magento 1, then in theory, it's only a matter of time before malware finds your site.

A good practice would be to have a fork of this repository https://github.com/magento/magento2 and bring the latest fixes into your code periodically. This would of course give you another reason to upgrade to the latest version since Magento 1 is no longer maintained.

You will have to reproduce all of your modules for Magento 2, there is absolutely no other way, And if you use the Data Migration tool, you should have an easy time bringing the data over. And the next point is going to be to create the theme for your site once more, there is no easy way to bring your theme over from M1 either.

Good luck my friend =D